# Regex findall between two optional patterns, return all if none

Tags: python, regex

I have a number of news articles, some which have intro and end statements. The possible combinations are...

- Some text about a news story.
- The BBC reports: Some text about a news story. Read more on BBC.com.
- The BBC reports: Some text about a news story.
- Some text about a news story. Read more on BBC.com.

What I would like to do is to return "Some text about a news story." in each case. I have the below regex which returns the 1st and 2nd example. I am strugling when there is either intro or end statements.

```
re.search(r'(?i)(?<=: ).*(?=Read more|Full story|\. Source)', str(doc)).group()

# "(?i)" to ignore case.
# "(?<=: )" to capture text after and excluding ": "
# ".*" match everything between the two patterns. 
# "(?=Read more|Full story|\. Source)" match everything before these three strings.
```

Comment: Try `re.search(r'(?i)(?:[^:\n]*:\s*|^)(.*?)(?:$|Read more|Full story|\. Source)', doc).group(1)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/glrPCm/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may use

```
import re
doc = "The BBC reports: Some text about a news story. Read more on BBC.com."
rx = r'(?i)(?:[^:\n]*:\s*|^)(.*?)(?:$|Read more|Full story|\. Source)'
m = re.search(rx, doc)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/glrPCm/1).

**Details**

- `(?i)` - ignore case flag
- `(?:[^:\n]*:\s*|^)` - a non-capturing group matching either 0+ chars other than `:` and a newline followed with `:` and then 0+ whitespaces or start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:$|Read more|Full story|\. Source)` - a non-capturing group matching `Read more`, `Full story` or `. Source`.